# How can I convert a list of character vectors to a single vector?

Tags: r, stringr

thanks for your time.

I am performing some data processing, and used `str_extract_all` from the `stringr` package to extract some data from a column.  My `str_extract_all` call used some regex logic to extract the appropriate information.

However, `str_extract_all` returns a list.  I need this list converted to a vector, so that I can include this vector onto my data frame as a new column.

Below is a reproducible example.  Here is my list returned by `str_extract_all`:

```
example_list <- list("[10]",
                     "[44]",
                     c("[9]", "[32]", "[98]"),
                     NA,
                     "[93]")
```

`example_list` looks like:

```
> example_list
[[1]]
[1] "[10]"

[[2]]
[1] "[44]"

[[3]]
[1] "[9]"  "[32]" "[98]"

[[4]]
[1] NA

[[5]]
[1] "[93]"
```

I would like this list to be converted to a vector, of the same length.  This is my desired vector:

```
desired_vector <- c("[10]",
                  "[44]",
                  c("[9], [32], [98]"),
                  NA,
                  "[93]")
```

This vector looks like this.

```
> desired_vector
[1] "[10]"            "[44]"            "[9], [32], [98]" NA                
"[93]"
```

Or, equivalently, as it would appear in the data frame and not printed out to the console, the `desired_vector` would appear as this:

```
[10]            
[44]            
[9], [32], [98]
NA
[93]
```

Note: The commas above in the `desired_vector` are not needed, spaces or no spaces are fine.

I have tried various methods I've found, including `unlist` and `flatten`.
Using `unlist` returns this not_desired vector:

```
 not_desired_vector <- unlist(example_list)
```

Which looks like this:

```
> not_desired_vector
[1] "[10]" "[44]" "[9]"  "[32]" "[98]" NA     "[93]"
```

---

To be clear, I would like the list to be returned as a vector of the same length as the original list, where the portion of the list with three successive elements is not returned as three elements of the vector, but as one character string within a single element of the vector.

Thanks again for your time - any push in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `sapply(example_list,FUN = function(x) if (all(is.na(x))) NA else paste(x,collapse = ", "))` would suffice.

Comment: Well-asked question with sample data, desired output, *and* methods already attempted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `toString` to each component simplifying down to a vector.  This will convert NA entries to the character string `"NA"` so fix those up.

```
res <- sapply(example_list, toString)
res[is.na(example_list)] <- NA
res
```

giving:

```
[1] "[10]"            "[44]"            "[9], [32], [98]" NA               
[5] "[93]"
```

This could be expressed in a single line like this:

```
ifelse(is.na(example_list), NA, sapply(example_list, toString))
```

or using magrittr pipes:

```
library(magrittr)
example_list %>% { ifelse(is.na(.), NA, sapply(., toString)) }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for you response - this worked great for my needs.  `toString` was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Isn't it best to avoid sapply because the output type is unknown? I suppose toString() tells us the output type, but I would still prefer something like vapply (because I don't know what other simplifications sapply might perform.)

Answer (score 3):

Using `tidyverse` tools `map_chr` and `str_c`, we can iterate over your list, concatenating all length > 1 vectors together with comma separators:

```r
example_list <- list("[10]",
                     "[44]",
                     c("[9]", "[32]", "[98]"),
                     NA,
                     "[93]")

library(tidyverse)
example_list %>% map_chr(~ str_c(., collapse = ", "))
#> [1] "[10]"          "[44]"          "[9], [32], [98]" NA             
#> [5] "[93]"
```

Created on 2018-09-26 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

The `deparse` function will sometimes give you useful results. It's not exactly like your desires, but might be useful in the future:

```
sapply(example_list, deparse)
[1] "\"[10]\""       "\"[44]\""        "c(\"[9]\", \"[32]\", \"[98]\")"
[4] "NA"             "\"[93]\""
```

And you could always clean it up with a bit of regex:

```
gsub("c\\(\\\"|\\\"|\\)", "", sapply(example_list, deparse) )
#[1] "[10]"            "[44]"            "[9], [32], [98]" "NA"              "[93]"
```

Method2:

```
sapply( example_list, paste, collapse=", ")
[1] "[10]"            "[44]"            "[9], [32], [98]" "NA"              "[93]"
```